# C# Linq different values printed than presented in debug mode

Tags: c#, linq

```
var counter=0;
var array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3,4};

var test = array.Select(a => counter++);

foreach (var item in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

When I run the code above the console prints 0,1,2,3,4.
However, when I expand test array in the debug mode I can see numbers from 10 to 14. Why??
Also, can you help me why the console does not print 1,2,3,4,5 as it should return incremented counter.

[image: DebugMode]

Comment: Use `array.Select(a => counter++).ToList()` and it will stop happening!

Comment: For the second part of the question you might want to read the docs on ++: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator . `counter++` returns counter before incrementing.

Comment: You're enumerating `test` multiple times while debugging which causes `counter` to be incremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the output keeps changing is that `test` isn't actually evaluated until you enumerate through it. So opening up the debug view causes it to evaluate the enumeration. Then every time you enumerate it, it will run again, each time the `counter` variable increasing. So you can get some funny results by running the `for` loop multiple times or printing out `test.First()` multiple times.

You can prevent this by forcing the enumerable to materialise into a list:

```
var test = array.Select(a => counter++).ToList();
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

As for why it starts at zero, that's because [`++`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) in this context is a post-increment operator meaning it returns the value and then increments. If you want it to start at 1, prefix the variable instead:

```
var test = array.Select(a => ++counter).ToList();
```

Comment: This is roughly what I thought but one thing I was a little unsure of is why it is that the result of `test` is 10-14 implying that counter has been incremented that high but `counter` itself is showing 5. Does the debugger deliberately not actually persist changes to counter when evaluating the enumerable or something? It doesn't look like it is needing refreshing (it usually greys things out when it thinks they aren't current).

Comment: @Chris `counter` would have been evaluated first, then the `test` after expanding the results view. The value for `counter` won't get automatically updated in the view until a line of code is executed.

Comment: So that suggests that it evaluated `test` twice then for some reason - once returning 5-9 because counter started at 5, and then a second time returning what we see as 10-14?

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. Why in the debug mode the values arent 5,6,7,8,9 instead of 10,11,12,13,14? As I understand that test is enumarated twice (1. when is printed in console, 2.when opening debug mode) not three times.

Comment: @Chris, there is a foreach in this code forcing to enumerate once 0-4. First time you inspect, it forces to enumerate again so you get 5-9. Then every time OP expands Result View it increments again. That's why watch window says *"Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable"*. These maths make sense as far as I can see. OP was expanding multiple times.

Comment: @derloopkat: I'm not in a position to test but I thought that once you expand results once then if you collapse it it won't tell you that expanding will enumerate because it has already enumerated.

Comment: @Chris, as you drag and drop current line, a reload icon comes up in Result View. Then when you expand you get 10-14.

Comment: @derloopkat: I'd have expected anything that caused the `Results View` to need to be updated to do the same for the `counter` variable. I don't think I'm going to worry about it too much though. In practice its not really relevant, I was just curious about debugger behaviour. :)

Comment: @Chris, I agree there, counter falls behind.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. When you just use the Select method, you get a lazy list, it means it will be evaluated when you access it. Here, you access it twice, when you execute the foreach and when you look in the debugger, each time, your select Func is getting executed, thus incrementing your counter. 
If you replace by

```
var test = array.Select(a => counter++).ToList();
```

It won't be lazy anymore, and will be executed once when you call ToList(). Yet, staying lazy might be interesting especially if you want to add some conditions later, for example appending some Where conditions, you wouldn't like your query to be executed before you're finished building it.

Your counter starts at zero because counter++ will first give you the value, then only increment it. If you want to start at one you can either initialize counter to 1 or replace counter++ by ++counter, it will be first incremented then returned.